# When do the HttpApplication.BeginRequest and EndRequest events fire relative to ActionFilter.OnResultExecuted in the MVC pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The reason I ask is that I am trying to run MVC side-by-side with WebForms.

For WebForms we use an HttpModule to open and close an NHibernate Session once per request - opening the session during HttpApplication.BeginRequest and HttpApplication.EndRequest. For MVC, the recommended method is to use an ActionFilterAttribute but to keep things simple I have decided to stick with the HttpModule.

However, I *am* using an ActionFilter to open and close Transactions.

I am getting some strange intermittent problems though and I'm curious whether the issue could be that the HttpApplication.EndRequest method is firing before the ActionFilter's OnResultExecuted method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the order of execution:

```
1. HttpApplication.BeginRequest
2. ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted
3. HttpApplication.EndRequest
```

The `HttpApplication.EndRequest` can never fire before `ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @cbp, sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx. There are even posters :-) As you can see the App.BeginRequest and App.EndRequest in ASP.NET are the first and last events that happen in the execution of the pipeline. Everything else happens in-between.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not saying I don't believe you, just looking for good documentation in general because I'm finding it hard to get MVC documentation for this sort of thing. For example, that link you provide is for .NET Web Forms and is all about the Page life cycle, which is not relevant to MVC.

Comment: @cbp, what do you think ASP.NET MVC is? An HTTP handler plugged into the ASP.NET execution pipeline. So it's lifetime is constrained inside this pipeline.